# adding numbers with comma in asp

Tags: asp.net

I've got a control panel in simple asp. It has do store basic info in my Microsoft SQL Server. I have 2 fields (compenso and diritti_di_segreteria) where my customer input costs. I need the sum of these fields as the Costo value.

```
Compenso = Trim(Request.Form("compenso"))
Compenso = Replace(compenso, ",", ".")
Diritti_di_segreteria = Trim(Request.Form("diritti_di_segreteria"))
Diritti_di_segreteria = Replace(diritti_di_segreteria, ",", ".")
Costo = (FormatNumber(Compenso, 2) * 1) + (FormatNumber(Diritti_di_segreteria, 2) * 1)
```

Now, if the number is without comma, the sum is perfect. If not, the result is a mess. Example: 20 + 30 results in 50, but 20,5 + 30.7 results in 512,00. I'm sure I'm missing something important here.

Answer (score 0):

You want to call FormatNumber after adding the data

```
Costo = FormatNumber((Compenso + Diritti_di_segreteria), 2);
```

Otherwise you are adding two strings together.